# ServiceStack.Licensing.RegisterLicense exception on Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, servicestack-text

I'm getting an exception with a call to ServiceStack.Licensing.RegisterLicense(string license) in a Xamarin Android App (this is a trivial concept app):

> {
>   System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for ServiceStack.LicenseUtils --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object
>   at ServiceStack.LicenseUtils..cctor () [0x00000] in
>   :0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at ServiceStack.Licensing.RegisterLicense (System.String
>   licenseKeyText) [0x00000] in :0
>   at
>   ServiceStackLicker.MainActivity+<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0
>   (System.Object param0, System.EventArgs param1) [0x0003b] in
>   c:\Users\ibLang\Documents\Projects\ServiceStackLicker\ServiceStackLicker\MainActivity.cs:35
>
> } 
>   System.TypeInitializationException

This is reproduced with just a blank Xamarin Android App with the ServiceStack.Text package installed. This code works fine in my other portable class libraries that use ServiceStack.Text, so I know that the license is valid.

In further investigation, I'm finding that I can't even make a simple Xamarin Android app do anything with ServiceStack.Text.

Does this work with Xamarin Android apps? Am I completely missing some initialization that I have in my other libraries? Is there a bug? What up!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the ServiceStack PCL libraries you need to install the [ServiceStack.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Client) NuGet package, i.e:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Client
```

This will also install the `ServiceStack.Text` package but more importantly the required PCL adapters for the different supported PCL providers like Android, iOS, etc.